# How to convert an array to a cstring?

Tags: nim-lang

I found ([here](https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/716)) the source of a program to compute the MD5 of a file using Nim.
This program no longer compiles (nim 1.4) as the implicit conversion between **array** to **cstring** has been disabled.

How can this be fixed?

```py
import md5
import os

proc calculateMD5Incremental(filename: string) : string =
  
  const blockSize: int = 8192
  var
    c: MD5Context
    d: MD5Digest
    f: File
    bytesRead: int = 0
    buffer: array[blockSize, char]
    byteTotal: int = 0
  
  #read chunk of file, calling update until all bytes have been read
  try:
    f = open(filename)
    
    md5Init(c)
    bytesRead = f.readBuffer(buffer.addr, blockSize)
    
    while bytesRead > 0:
      byteTotal += bytesRead
      md5Update(c, buffer, bytesRead) # <--- HERE buffer should be cstring
      bytesRead = f.readBuffer(buffer.addr, blockSize)
    
    md5Final(c, d)
  
  except IOError:
    echo("File not found.")
  finally:
    if f != nil:
      close(f)
  
  result = $d

if paramCount() > 0:
  let arguments = commandLineParams()
  echo("MD5: ", calculateMD5Incremental(arguments[0]))
else:
  echo("Must pass filename.")
  quit(-1)
```

Note: I'm more interested in the general question and not in MD5, this was the example that came to hand.

Comment: even though md5 is tangential to the question, there is an implementation in stdlib: https://nim-lang.org/docs/md5.html

Comment: @pietroppeter hi! I didn’t get this sorry: the snippet uses the library to compute the hash of a file. Is there an implementation taking a file as argument?

Comment: Ah you are right, I did not even notice the snippet uses already md5 from stdlib and that what the code does is to compute in a memory efficient way computing it by chunks. Ignore my comment above, the code you report looks fine to me and the fix you provide in the answer is also fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your answer you turned array into string with `$`. This though does not return `"ciao"` but `"['c', 'i', 'a', 'o']"`. Not sure if you want that but proper way to do the conversion is as follows:

```py
const blockSize: int = 4
var
  c: cstring
  buffer: array[blockSize, char]
  
buffer = ['c','i','a','o']
c = cast[cstring](create(char, blockSize + 1))
moveMem(c[0].addr, buffer[0].addr, blockSize)

assert c == "ciao"
```

Mind that this is optimal unsafe solution. If you want to be safe but little slower the you can use this code:

```py
const blockSize: int = 4
var
  c: cstring
  buffer: array[blockSize, char]
  temp: string  
  
buffer = ['c','i','a','o']
temp.setLen(blockSize)
for i in 0..<blockSize:
  temp[i] = buffer[i]
c = temp

assert c == "ciao"
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** In this context this is completely wrong. As pointed out in the accepted answer, $array will render it in a "screen friendly" way.

## Correct implementation

The working procedure for md5(fromFile):

```py
proc calculateMD5Incremental(filename: string) : string = 
  const blockSize: int = 8192
  var
    c: MD5Context
    d: MD5Digest
    f: File
    s: cstring
    bytesRead: int = 0
    buffer: array[blockSize, char]
    byteTotal: int = 0
  
  #read chunk of file, calling update until all bytes have been read
  try:
    f = open(filename)
    
    md5Init(c)
    bytesRead = f.readBuffer(buffer.addr, blockSize)
    
    while bytesRead > 0:
      byteTotal += bytesRead
      s = cast[cstring](create(char, blockSize + 1))
      moveMem(s[0].addr, buffer[0].addr, blockSize)
      md5Update(c, s, bytesRead)
      bytesRead = f.readBuffer(buffer.addr, blockSize)
    
    md5Final(c, d)
  
  except IOError:
    stderr.writeLine("ERROR: File not found: ", filename)
  finally:
    if f != nil:
      close(f)
  
  result = $d
```

---

#### Wrong conversion

~I found that a regular string is accepted so `$buffer` will convert the array to a valid string:~

```
const blockSize: int = 4
var
  c: cstring
  buffer: array[blockSize, char]
  
  
buffer = ['c','i','a','o']
c = $buffer
```

Comment: yes, conversion between regular string to cstring is implicit: https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#types-cstring-type